# Accessing session in PHP command line?

Tags: javascript, php, session, websocket

I understand that command line is no web server, so you can't access `$_SESSION`. But I don't know what else to do.

I've been following this tutorial to create a chat using websockets: http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html

My problem is that, I do not know how to get the username of the message sender securely. I could include it in the  message send function but since it's in Javascript, everyone can just edit their username to someone elses.

How could I securely get the username of the user, which is `$_SESSION['username']`?

```
var Server;
Server = new FancyWebSocket('ws://0.0.0.0:9000');
send( "test" );
```

I'm open to all kind of suggestions, like alternatives to websockets. I'm creating a realtime chat for my website.

Comment: The HTTP headers, including cookies, are available to the WS server during the handshake.  In that specific server, the headers are available in the user class under the property `$headers` implemented as an array.  I'll add a thorough answer later (and add a feature request to parse cookies), but that should help get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First alternative is, of course, AJAX requests.  AJAX doesn't have the problems of not being able to quickly and easily access the sessions that WebSockets has.  Any sufficiently frequent sample rate is indistinguishable from real time.

Now, to my rather long-winded solution implemented in WebSockets:

The HTTP headers are available to the WebSocket server during the handshake, including the cookies.  In the server that you're using, [PHP-Websockets](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets), the headers are stored in the `$headers` property.

For instance:

```
var_dump($user->headers);
array(14) {
  ["get"]=>
  string(8) "/echobot"
  ["host"]=>
  string(14) "127.0.0.1:9000"
  ...snip...
  ["cookie"]=>
   string(100) "PHPSESSID=jan9uknpc06mk4ddghph4870t1; MyCookie=My+Value%21%40%23%24%25; MyNonhttponlyCookie=My+Value"
}
```

These cookies were generated from

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['Hi!'] = array('Hello!', 'where' => 'world!');
setcookie('MyCookie', 'My Value;!@#$%', 0, '/', '127.0.0.1', false, true);
setcookie('MyNonhttponlyCookie', 'My Value', 0, '/', '127.0.0.1', false, false);
```

Thus, the value of `$user->headers['cookie']` is a semicolon and space (`;`) delimited collection of key value pairs, where the values are URL encoded and separated from its key with an equal sign.  (PHP complains if you put reserved characters in the cookie name. Thus the cookie key can not contain any url encoded values.)

A quick way to extract these are as follows

```
$cookies = array();
$cookiesParts = explode('; ', $user->headers['cookie']);
foreach ($cookiesParts as $cookieParts) {
    $interimCookie = explode('=', $cookieParts);
    $cookies[$interimCookie[0]] = urldecode($interimCookie[1]);
}
var_dump($cookies);

array(3) {
  ["PHPSESSID"]=>
  string(26) "jan9uknpc06mk4ddghph4870t1"
  ["MyCookie"]=>
  string(14) "My Value;!@#$%"
  ["MyNonhttponlyCookie"]=>
  string(8) "My Value"
}
```

We now have the session ID. Double check with `session_name()`, which will give you the key of the cookie that actually holds the session ID.

We could serialize and unserialize the session file as stored in the server, which is pointed at by `session_save_path()`... but I want to cheat.

Because the built-in session system locks the session files, we can't just keep the session file open and constantly watch for changes, nor can we lock the file ourselves for long periods of time.

It would be ideal if we could use the `__get()` and `__set()` magic methods here in the same way we'd use the `$_SESSION` superglobal (such as `$myUser->_session['key'] = 'value';`), but PHP does not allow treating these methods as arrays.  Instead, we have to set a more mundanely named method.

```
<?php
class MyUser extends WebSocketUser {
    public $session_id; // gets set somewhere. Good place is probably is your implementation of the `connected($user)` abstract method.

    public getSession($key) {
        session_id($this->session_id);
        session_start();
        $val = $_SESSION[$key];
        session_write_close(); // very important!
        return $val;
    }

    public setSession($key, $value) {
        session_id($this->session_id);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION[$key] = value;
        session_write_close(); // still very important!
    }
}
```

(Note: I'm also pointing my [feature request](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets/issues/44) at this question, to base my eventual implementation of cookie parsing and session handling here, so that I can remember my research tonight as I work.)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help! I don't really know how to implement and use the MyUser class. Could you help me out?

Comment: In your `FancyWebSocket` class, you'll need to assign the protected property `$userClass` to be the name of your new user class.  Other than that, it's basic OOP.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not following you. I do not have a `FancyWebSocket` class, I have a `PHPWebSocket` class. And there's nothing called `$userClass` in any of my files?

Comment: @kopa Sorry, was looking at the snippet of JS you shared above, and assumed you'd named your PHP class the same, which is where the `FancyWebSocket` came from. When you said you were following the tutorial from http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html ... Did you mean the only actual tutorial on that page, which uses https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets ?  Or, did you mean one of the several others listed as alternatives?

Comment: I followed the PHPWebSockets tutorial, at the bottom of the tutorial it says `A simple and functional chat application using the PHPWebSockets can be downloaded from here.` - that's the code I'm using.

Comment: A var_dump of $headers didn't contain anything named as `cookie`. But it did contain this: `string(42) "Cookie: unique_id=NjIuMTk4LjczLjI0NQ%3D%3D"`. Is this what I'm looking for?

Comment: That certainly looks like a valid PHP session ID.  Give it a try and see what you get.

Comment: I think I got it now! I was connecting to the WS server through the servers IP address, instead of the domain name. So of course it couldn't find my PHP session ID. Thank you for your help!