# Access Session in PHP Socket

Tags: php, session, websocket

I need to access the Session in my `PHP Web-Socket`. I've already got the `SessionID` from the header but if I try to start the session, I get the Error:

> PHP Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers
>   already send by (output started at ....)

I tried (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31532785/8510512):

```
session_id($sessionID);
session_start();
```

Comment: It says that the headers are already sent, so you probably outputted something already. Since you don't show any other code, we can't tell you what the actual problem is.